# IPv6 /48 subnetting on KVM guests

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, ipv6

I have a dedicated server that has been assigned a /48 IPv6 address block.  That server is running several Linux guests with macvtap networking.  I want each guest to have a /64 block, but I can't seem to pin down the right configuration.  I can assign the whole /48 to a guest and it works fine, but anything else and I get various results (all ping responses are lost on their way to the server, or simply a `connect: Network is unreachable` error when I try to run `ping6`).

My service provider has given me the usable address (2604:XXXX:XX14::2/48) and a gateway address (2604:XXXX:XX14::1).  They seem to be using a Hurricane Electric tunnel to provide the IPv6 service, if that changes anything.

Comment: Why do you need to assign more that one IPv6 address to a guest? IPv6 delegation gives you a prefix smaller than the standard _network_ `/64`. Many business-grade routers can then automatically assign individual `/64` networks from the smaller prefix. You can use these for separate router interfaces. With a `/48` delegation, you can create `65,536` different `/64` networks, and each network can have `18,446,744,073,709,551,616` hosts per `/64` network.

Comment: Some routers have issues with "nested subnets", even with IPv6 (but especially so with IPv4). The HE system is very complete, but if they are truly using a 6to4 tunnel, that has quite a few limitations. Some information about this provider and your instance and whether they're using a 6to4 tunnel would help this question quite a bit.

Comment: I did a traceroute from my local network (running a HE 6to4 tunnel) to the /48, and all the hosts along the way resolved to some.thing.he.net.  The traceroute died out in the datacenter's network but before hitting the gateway IP I was given.

Comment: You're approaching this from the wrong direction. Instead of assigning to hosts, you generally should assign subnets to each virtual network.

Comment: The guests are using macvtap for network, which functions as a dumb switch between the guests and the host's Ethernet port.

Comment: Splitting up the host's IPv4 subnet was as simple as assigning a static IP from the supplied range to each guest.

Comment: Why use macvtap instead of routing normally, then?

Comment: I decided to use macvtap because my goal was four servers for the price of one, and macvtap seemed to be a simple, well-performing way.  They all work great on IPv4, I merely want to add IPv6.

Answer (score 2):

Your upstream provider has gone outside the normal v6 addressing scheme, each while they assigned you a 48 your network connection should be a 64 and a route added for the 48 to your v6/64 address, others may use a /126 for P2P links.

Then each container you add with a /64 address will be locally connected and routed. You can also request that they accept route advertisements (RA) or setup a bgp peer and use exabgp, gobgp, frr, etc to establish the routes.

With IPv6 you assign subnets, which many of us a are lazy and don't do with v4 (although you can route a v4/32 same as a v6/64

Macvtap is not a dumb switch, it's a pass through port and won't work the way you've attempted.

Comment: If the provider had in fact configured the `/48` as a link prefix, then that would indeed be a bad configuration. But it's not clear from the provided information that that is actually what the provider did.

Comment: Agreed there's a lot of missing details, but if it works when he assigns an address in the same /48 I made the assumption.

Comment: I'll try to clarify a little: Given an address `2604:XXXX:XX14::2/48`, if I configure a guest's `/etc/network/interfaces` to use that address, I can ping it as `2604:XXXX:XX14::2`.  If I configure a guest with any address except `2604:XXXX:XX14::2` (such as `2604:XXXX:XX14:abcd::2`) it doesn't work (and the guest decides there is no IPv6 connection at all).

Comment: Are you still using `/48` masks for both?

Comment: Yes, I am.  It's the only way it works at all.

Comment: Did adding `2604:XXXX:XX14:bad::1dea/48` work?? It should since Its the same subnet, I assume these containers also have a default route via `2604:XXXX:XX14::1/48`